# Mysql date error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, where-clause

I have spent a bit of time on this and can get it to work locally, but when I publish the query doesn't work.
I have a table where I want to sort the date field greater or equal than today ascending.
The program I am using generates this:

```
 $sql = $sql."     masterdiary.`extras`,"."\r\n";
 $sql = $sql."     masterdiary.`Day`"."\r\n";
 $sql = $sql." From"."\r\n";
 $sql = $sql."     masterdiary   masterdiary"."\r\n";
 $sql = $sql." Where "."\r\n";
 $sql = $sql."     masterdiary.date >= DATE()"."\r\n";

 $sql_ext = $sql_ext." Order by"."\r\n";
 $sql_ext = $sql_ext."     masterdiary.`date` Asc"."\r\n";
```

Could somebody help me rectify this please, I have tried a lot of combinatios but still get this error :

```
......to use near ') AND (1=0) Order by masterdiary.`date` Asc limit 0,1'
 at line 31
```

MySQL version
•cpsrvd 11.64.0.40
•Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
•PHP extension: mysqli

Comment: Please, provide all lines of code related to building the query in `$sql_ext`.

Comment: In addition, show the final `$sql` string *after* all the code has built it up. It's easier to notice syntax errors in the final SQL query than to imagine what the SQL will be after all the code has built it.

Comment: When dynamically constructing SQL, echo/vardump/printf the resulting SQL string. That will show the actual SQL text that the code intends to send to the database. Then you can find the problem in the SQL statement, and then go back and make the appropriate fixes in the code so that the SQL syntax is constructed properly.  (That is much more efficient than the "try this, try this, try this," to attempt to fix the problem. (Fortunately, my car mechanic doesn't use this approach... he *diagnoses* the problem, and then fixes it.)

Comment: Where is `) AND (1=0)` I don't see that in your code.

Comment: `$sql = $sql.` can just be `$sql .=`, after the first assignment. You also don't need the assignment on every line, strings can extend multiple lines.

Comment: This is such a tiresome way of presenting code :-(

Comment: @Strawberry: you would prefer a link to an image on imgur.com  ?  `:)`

Comment: @spencer7593 you know me too well ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The expression `DATE()` isn't valid in MySQL; the `DATE()` function requires an argument. To verify, test it with a simple statement:

```
 SELECT DATE() ;
```

returns an error

```
Error Code: 1064
... error in your SQL syntax... right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

One of the problems is here:

```
 $sql = $sql."     masterdiary.date >= DATE()"."\r\n";
                                       ^^^^^^
```

Maybe we wanted MySQL to return the current date?

```
 $sql = $sql."     masterdiary.date >= DATE(NOW())"."\r\n";
                                       ^^^^------^
```

I recommend testing the expressions in simple statements, before we include them in a more complicated statements. e.g.

```
 SELECT DATE(NOW()) ;
```

Comment: Good catch. Here's a reference to the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Comment: Tried it and still error
'code'
        $sql = $sql."     masterdiary.`extras`,"."\r\n";
        $sql = $sql."     masterdiary.`Day`"."\r\n";
        $sql = $sql." From"."\r\n";
        $sql = $sql."     masterdiary   masterdiary"."\r\n";
        $sql = $sql." Where"."\r\n";
        $sql = $sql."     masterdiary.date >= DATE(NOW())"."\r\n";
        $sql_ext = $sql_ext." Order by"."\r\n";
        $sql_ext = $sql_ext."     masterdiary.`date` Asc"."\r\n";

Comment: Tried it and still error

       `code` $sql = $sql."     masterdiary.`extras`,"."\r\n";
       `code`$sql = $sql."     masterdiary.`Day`"."\r\n";
       `code`$sql = $sql." From"."\r\n";
       `code`$sql = $sql."     masterdiary   masterdiary"."\r\n";
      `code`$sql = $sql." Where"."\r\n";
      `code`$sql = $sql."     masterdiary.date >= DATE(NOW())"."\r\n";
      `code`$sql_ext = $sql_ext." Order by"."\r\n";
      `code` $sql_ext = $sql_ext." masterdiary.`date` Asc"."\r\n";

error  right syntax to use near 'Where (1=0) Order by masterdiary.`date` Asc limit 0,1' at line 32

Comment: This answer highlighted just *one* problem that I spotted. (I have no way of knowing what SQL statement is being sent to the database.) I *strongly* recommend you see the comments (on the question) left by Bill Karwin and me. The code should output the actual SQL text that's being sent to the database. Take that SQL statement to another client and get the syntax debugged. Do that first. Once you get the SQL fixed, then come back to the code that generates the SQL, and figure out what changes are needed to generate the proper SQL syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your help, 
not getting the error now, just no records!!
but I can fix that..Dave

Comment: The condition `(1=0)` will never evaluate to `TRUE`; there are no rows in any table anywhere that will satisfy that condition. (If we can't see the SQL text that is being submitted, then we can't debug it. And we need to debug the SQL *before* we can debug code that generates the SQL.)